# Error: Database Connection Problem. (Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock)

Tags: mysql, thrift

I installed xampp in my Ubuntu 16.0
So, I think it(xampp) runs mysql server. I am doing a project (backend:Python and fronend: PHP)
When I am executing python file it is saying giving the error

> **database connection problem (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)") 
> No handlers could be found for logger "thrift.server.TServer"**

Then I did, 
I created a link file of /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.scok file and renamed it as mysqld.sock and I moved this file to location /var/run/mysqld (by creating new folder mysqld).
Even It is giving same error.